# How to fire an event on close of drop down in Bootstrap select with multiple selection in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select with multiple selection in an application using Backbone.js . Now I want to fire an event when all the selection is done and drop down closes. change event will fire on every selection which I don't want.

My code is below

```js
    var agentMetricView = ParentView.extend({

  events: {
   'mouseup .js-table-agent': 'adjustAgentTable',
   'change .js-select': 'changeDropdown',
  },
      
  changeDropdown: function(event) {
   debugger;
   /*this.selectedSkill = $("#skill-agent").find("option:selected").text();*/
   console.log($(event.currentTarget.id).val());
  }
      
     });

 return agentMetricView;
```

```html
 <span class="dropdown-text">Dept:</span>
      <select  class="selectpicker left_float js-select" data-select="selectedDept" multiple data-hide-disabled="true" data-size="5" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="120px">
         <option>Option 1</option>
         <option>Option 2</option>
         <option>Option 3</option>
         <option>Option 4</option>
      </select>
```

silviomoreto has provided an option but i don't know how to use it in Backbone

```
$selectpicker.on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
    console.log('hide');
});
```

check [Bootstrap-Select issue #216 Change Event](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/216)

When I add the below event listener it does not fire

```
'hide.bs.dropdown .selectpicker ': 'changeDropdown',
```

Comment: May be there is no space after `hide` in the backbone events node? Try `'hide .bs.dropdown': 'changeDropdown',` or `'hide .selectpicker': 'changeDropdown',` there

Comment: @MaxZuber I thanks for the reply, I found the solution the problem was due to selectpicker class when I am using a custom class it is working this seems to be the answer 'hide.bs.dropdown .js-select': 'changeDropdown', don't know why

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('#yourid').on('hide.bs.select', function (e) {alert('test');});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution although the actual reason I am not clear about. The problem is with using bootstrap class ".selectpicker" when I am using my own custom class ".js-select" it is working. This seems to be the answer

```
'hide.bs.dropdown .js-select': 'changeDropdown',
```

instead of this

```
'hide.bs.dropdown .selectpicker ': 'changeDropdown',
```

Reason I have no idea I some one tells I will be happy to know.